# Hide Output of Composer Install Command

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-envoy

Is there a way that we can hide the output of the command `composer install`?

I run a deployment script for my Laravel application, and the output is messy when it prints hundreds of lines of:

- Installing app/package (v1.2.1),
  Loading from cache,
  etc. etc.

There doesn’t seem to be any flags that hide the output as far as I can see. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-q` ? I've just tried it on the command line, at least.

Comment: One tip - in cronjobs and other scripts, I default to using the verbose forms of command line options. So, in this case, I would usually use the argument `--quiet`